# jquery input append items and split list into columns with a MAX limit

Tags: jquery, indexing, append, multiple-columns

With this code I can split a list into columns with a **max column limit (8)**,
it works, but the problem comes when I add new items by a text input:

new items are added, but there are some bugs with the lists and with new items..

```
$(window).load(function(){
    splitColumns();
});

function addFun(value){
    $('.LAST').append('<div class="BB"><span>'+value+'</span><button onclick="$(this.parentElement).remove();">x</button></div>');
    splitColumns();
}


function splitColumns(){
    var itemindex = 0;
    var Jlistobj = null;
    $('.AA .BB').each(function(){
        if (itemindex % 8 == 0){
            Jlistobj = $('<div class="AA"></div>');
        }
        Jlistobj.append($(this));
        $('.cont').append(Jlistobj);
        itemindex++;
    });
    $('.cont .AA:first').css({'display':'none'});
    $('.cont .AA:last').addClass('LAST');
}
```

When I try to add a new item, it is not only added to the last column, but also to the other columns
and the max columns limit is not longer respected...

It is driving me crazy.. Any help is really much appreciated

Thank you in advance

### Please have a look at this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ujd4k/1/)**

(press return to add items with text input)

Comment: What you want the duplicate item should not append in list from textbox?

Comment: @MohitArora No, I want to add new item only to the last column, then do the column split (if the last column has reached max limit 8, split the new item in a new column)

Comment: @banana I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, please help

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gVASy/4/) try this,

```
function addFun(value)
{
var array=[];
$(".AA,.BB").each(function(i,v){
    array.push($(this).find('span').text());
});
if(jQuery.inArray( value, array )> -1)  
   {      
        alert("already availble..");      
   }
else     
   {  
        $('.LAST').append('<div class="BB"><span>'+value+'</span><button   onclick="$(this.parentElement).remove();">x</button></div>');        
   }  
}
```

Comment: Please look at my fiddle: I don't want to prevent duplicates, but my problem is that the "columns split" is not respected properly whrn I try to add new items to the last column. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Change your `addFun` function like this:-

```
function addFun(value){
 var last=$('.AA.LAST');
 if(last.find('.BB').length<8){
   $('.LAST').append('<div class="BB"><span>'+value+'</span><button onclick="$(this.parentElement).remove();">x</button></div>');
  }else{ 
     last.removeClass('LAST');
     last.after('<div class="AA LAST"></div>');
     $('.LAST').append('<div class="BB"><span>'+value+'</span><button onclick="$(this.parentElement).remove();">x</button></div>');
   }   
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ujd4k/4/)

Comment: Look at the code in your answer at line `var last=$('.AA.LAST');`: if I use `.AA.LAST` with no space between, it works. But if I use the space between `.AA .LAST` it does not work :/ I really don't understand.. Can you explain me why?

Comment: @Edward `.AA.LAST` will select the div that have both classes `AA` and `LAST` but if you use `.AA .LAST` with space it means you are finding the element with class name `LAST` inside element that have class `AA`.